# The Inflate Tool Not Working on Donut

Tags: sculpting

I'm currently following the blender tutorial by Blender Guru. Everything has been going fine until part 5 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_OrMDOK-Og) where he uses the inflate tool. After I have applied all the modifiers (Shrinkwrap, Solidify, and Subdivision for the icing, and Subdivision for the donut), however, the inflate tool does not work on the icing. Some things I have tried are:

- Resetting the brush settings and setting the strength to 1.0
- Revert back to a version where the modifiers have not been applied and try to use the inflate tool
- Apply the Solidify and Subdivision modifiers for the icing, but not the Shrinkwrap

At this point, I'm not sure what to do and would appreciate some guidance. I've uploaded two files, one with the modifiers not applied, and the other with modifiers applied. Additionally, my blender version is 3.3.1.

File with no modifiers applied: [image]

File with modifiers applied: [image]

Comment: Hello could you please tell what minute of the tutorial? Edit: OK it's 11:30 apparently

Comment: The Inflate brush works fine if you apply the Shrinkwrap, see: https://zupimages.net/up/23/09/s9bw.gif It won't work if you don't apply it because it will continue to stick to the donut